# Trying to arrange images using css

Tags: css

Here is the code I am using so far. I have 6 images that I am trying to arrange and make responsive as well.

Idea is like this 
    image -blank space - image

image -----blank space -----image

```
 image -blank space - image
```

When I squeeze the page they do not end up stacked uniformly on top of each other. The spaces need to go away so all I have is 6 images on top of each other. CSS below followed by html

```css
.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
/** North Scottsdale */

.nsdl {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 175px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-image: url("/images/dphotos/test2a.png");
}
/** break1 */

.break1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 95px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
/** Scottsdale */

.sdl {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-image: url("/images/dphotos/test2a.png");
}
/** Tempe */

.tmpe {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 35px;
  padding: 10 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-image: url("/images/dphotos/test2a.png");
}
/** break2 */

.break2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 475px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
/** Downtown */

.dtown {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-image: url("/images/dphotos/test2a.png");
}
/** West Side */

.wside {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 175px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-image: url("/images/dphotos/test2a.png");
}
/** break1 */

.break3 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 95px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
/** UPTOWN */

.utown {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 120px;
  padding: 10 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-image: url("/images/dphotos/test2a.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="nsdl" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2> NORTH SCOTTSDALE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center"> </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="sdl" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>SCOTTSDALE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="tmpe" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>TEMPE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center"> </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="dtown" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>DOWNTOWN</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="wside" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>WEST SIDE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center"> </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="utown" style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>UPTOWN</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to control the size of your images (in `%` widths) at various screen sizes when used inside a container element.

Comment: If you don't want to take to much time and can use external libs. Try to figure out Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/). There grid system can help you a lot. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: thanks for the link. I am fairily new and learning still. I need to find good places to show me examples and concepts so I can understand ow to do this properly sometimes reading makes it worse and gets me very mixed up. I know this is probably easy to most of you but it takes me forever to "understand" as a 5 years old why or how things go together

Comment: I am going to read through and see what I can come up with.

Comment: http://foodie.azrideshare.com/locations/arizona?id=34 <-- testing this on here.

Comment: Using a module in joomla - this is not responsive hence why I am trying to recreate otherwise --> http://foodie.azrideshare.com/locations/arizona <-- has the end result if I can get it working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at a number of frameworks like Bootstrap, Skeleton and Zurb Foundation and use their CSS grid components. Look into how they control the size of various page regions with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) using a mobile first approach.

You can definitely roll your own solution too. Here's an example.

```html
<div class="img-group">
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=1">  
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=2"> 
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=3"> 
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=4"> 
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=5"> 
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=6"> 
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=7"> 
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=8"> 
  </div>
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=9"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.img-group img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img-holder {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@media ( min-width: 448px ) {
  .img-holder {
    width: 33.333%;
    padding: 0.75%;
  }
}

@media ( min-width: 779px ) {
  .img-holder {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 2%;
  }
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uutwb4z2/).

First you make your images responsive. The simplest version of doing so is setting them to `display: block;` and `max-width: 100%;`. Setting the max width means they'll try to take up their parent element's width as long as they don't exceed their own intrinsic width. For example, if the parent element is `700px` wide and the image is `600px` wide, it won't stretch to fit the `700px` of space. It will stop at `600px`.

Now you place your images in container elements that you'll control with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Use percentage widths (i.e. `width: 25%;` ) so they stay nice and fluid.

You might be wondering what `box-sizing: border-box;` does. It says that `padding` should be included as a part of your `width` definition. Normally if you have `width: 25%; padding: 1%;` the total width of your element would be `27%` as `1% + 25% + 1% = 27%`.